# HTTP access to SSAS server over IIS server

Tags: sql-server, iis, ssas, olap

I try to make the HTTP connection Http access to SSAS (MS Analysis Services) server over my IIS server

*i used guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0

When I try to make the connection from Microsoft SQL server Managment Studio 
over conn string:
http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll

error raised: The remote server returned an error (405) Method Not Allowed. (System)
i didnt find a solution

 how to solve this problem?

Comment: Facing similar issue can some one help